# Проблема со страницей отзывов сайта

Tags: python, django, slug, django-template

Делаю страницу с отзывами о сайте компании. На ней отображаются оставленные отзывы и форма. Использую FormView и DetailView для вывода этого дела, но вылезает такая ошибка:

```
Generic detail view ReviewsDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

Не совсем понимаю какой pk или slug здесь использовать...

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, request
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin, FormView
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from .models import *
from .forms import *

....


class ReviewsDetailView(FormView, DetailView):
    active = ['reviews']
    model = Review
    form_class = ReviewForm
    template_name = 'mainApp/reviews.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['reviews_list'] = Review.objects.all()
        context['review_form'] = ReviewForm()
        return context



    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path('reviews/', views.ReviewsDetailView.as_view(), name='reviews'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Review(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    message = models.TextField(verbose_name='Отзыв пользователя')
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Дата')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.date:
            self.date = datetime.datetime.now()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Отзыв'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Отзывы'
```

**Шаблон**

```
<div class="container block">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 offset-1">
        <h1>Отзывы</h1>
        <hr width="206">
        <p class="review-text">
          Что такое отзыв о работе агентства недвижимости — это признание того, что агентство реально помогает совершать сделки с недвижимостью. Также отзыв об агентстве недвижимости помогает этому агентству сделать свою работу еще лучше, учесть ошибки, как свои, так и других агентств. Ваши отзывы помогают нам быть лучшим агентством недвижимости Ульяновска. Мы каждый день стремимся к улучшению качества обслуживания своих клиентов и росту профессионализма наших сотрудников.
        </p>

        {% if reviews_list %}
        {% for review in reviews_list %}
        <div class="comment-block review-block blue">
          <p class="commentator-name">{{review.last_name}} {{review.name}}</p>
          <p class="comment-text">
            {{review.message}}
          </p>
          <p class="date comment-d">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {{review.date|date:"Y-m-d"}}
          </p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}




        <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
          <h4>Оставьте свой отзыв</h4>
          <div class="reg-for-sell">
            <form class="sell-form" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="name-last_name">
                <div class="form-group name-folder">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" placeholder="Ваше имя">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group name-folder">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputNamber1" placeholder="Ваша фамилия">
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control message" rows="6" placeholder="Ваш отзыв"></textarea>
              </div>

                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-reg-for-view" type="submit" value="Добавить">
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>




    </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Вот так выглядит эта страница[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В модели фирмы должно быть поле:
`slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='slug')`

В модели комментариев:
`post = models.ForeignKey(МОДЕЛЬ_ФИРМЫ, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')`

В urls:
`path('reviews/<slug:slug>/', views.DetailPost.as_view(), name='detail'),`

Примерно так. А вообще смотрите материал на тему ForeignKey там будет более подробное объяснение и показаны некоторые нюансы..

Comment: Нет нет, я наверное не совсем так объяснил, нет никакой модели фирмы. Грубо говоря, это просто отзыв о сайте. На этой страничке с отзывами есть форма, пользователь заполняет её и на странице появляется его отзыв. То есть отзыв не относится к какой-то определенной фирме, для которой надо использовать ForeignKey

Comment: Я добавил скрин этой страницы, можешь посмотреть о чем я говорю

Comment: Могу ошибаться (может гуру поправят) но без привязки будет сложно. Все же коммент должен к чему-то цепляться. Пусть к пользователю вместо фирмы. Вообще без привязок надо проверить как до своего компа доберусь. З.Ы. В любом случае к пользователю у вас должна быть привязка иначе поля имя и фамилия бесполезны

Comment: На этом сайте я уже делал форму для обратной связи, она ни к чему не цеплялась. Инфа, которую оставляет пользователь, просто висит в админке. Но в отличии от этого случая, там я использовал только FormView и проблем никаких не возникло. А тут же надо и форму вывести, чтобы её можно было заполнить, и отобразить уже имеющиеся отзывы. А как это сделать я ума не приложу...

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что смысла использовать DetailView вовсе не было)